# Hide back button text in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xaml, user-interface, xamarin

I want to hide text of back button in Xamarin on iOS, I've tried:

```
<Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
<Setter Property="BackButtonTitle" Value="" />
</Style>
```

and this code:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentPage">
<Setter Property="NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle" Value="" />
</Style>
```

But text still appears

**SOLVED:**

iOS renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ContentPage), typeof(BackButtonPag))]
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(BackButtonNav))]

public class BackButtonPag : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            if (NavigationController != null)
                NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);
        }
    }

    public class BackButtonNav : NavigationRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            NavigationBar.TopItem.BackBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem("", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, null);
        }
    }
```

Also add this

```
NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle = ""
```

to Main.xaml of your MasterDetailPage

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600713/xamarin-forms-how-to-hide-back-button-title

Comment: "NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false)" hides whole button, 
"UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment" hides text, but a back arrow on a navigation bar changes its position

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32600713/xamarin-forms-how-to-hide-back-button-title) said ,you can you can use an empty string for the Back button title:

```
NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, "");
```

Or you can  set the title of `UIBarButtonItem` as clear

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
  {
     // . . .
     var attribute = new UITextAttributes();
     attribute.TextColor = UIColor.Clear;
     UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(attribute, UIControlState.Normal);
     UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(attribute, UIControlState.Highlighted);
     //. . .

     return true;
  }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this set all toolbar items as having no text color?